# datatable overlap issue in jquery

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, datatable, datatables

I'm using jquery datatable I added bootstrap dropdown to my datatble, but datatable footer content is overlapped with dropdown here is the screenshot, Please suggest me the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the z-index position for your left search section. It will solve the overlap issue.

Comment: Please share your code or live link to take a look. Thanks